# Funções inline em iteração

Tags: c++

Em vários artigos,li que ao adicionar uma função inline dentro de uma iteração(while,for) gera um consumo desnecessário dos recursos do sistema.

Escrever:

```
#include <iostream>

inline int cubo(int n){
    return n*n*n;
}

int main(){
    for(int i = 0; i<40; i++){
        std::cout << cubo(3) << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Não seria o mesmo que escrever:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    for(int i = 0; i<40; i++){
        std::cout << 3*3*3 << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Algo como,o compilador irá copiar a função para cada repetição,ao invés de fazer o acima.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O especificador `inline` tem dois usos bem distintos. O primeiro é dar a dica ao compilador de que aquela função provavelmente vai ter melhor desempenho se for substituída na chamada. A segunda, e talvez negligenciada, é permitir que a função seja definida duas vezes. Vou explicar:

Suponha que você tenha um cabeçalho `matematica.hpp` com a função assim:

```
int cubo(int n) {
    return n*n*n;
}
```

Agora crie dois arquivos de código diferentes, um com a função `main` e outro com uma outra função qualquer. Se ambos incluírem o seu cabeçalho, ambos vão definir uma função `cube`. Na hora de gerar o executável final isso dará problema por que o linker não saberá qual das duas usar (mesmo sendo idênticas). Se adicionar `inline` na definição esse problema some. O linker meramente assume duas funções `inline` com o mesmo nome são iguais e usa uma das duas sem dar erro. Ou seja: com o `inline` você pode definir funções em cabeçalhos. Isso é necessário por que para efetivar a otimização, o compilador precisa de fato ter a definição da função em todas os arquivos.

Agora o ponto interessante: compiladores são espertos. Eles vão tomar a iniciativa de otimizar a função com ou sem a sua *dica* do `inline`. Da mesma forma, o compilador pode escolher **não** otimizar se ele concluir que os custos são maiores que os benefícios. Por exemplo, seu código, seja com ou sem o `inline` produz resultado idêntico quando compilado com `-O2` (otimize velocidade, não agressivamente). Mas se você deixar, por exemplo, a função maior (experimente adicionar um `cout` dentro dela) o compilador escolherá não aplicar a otimização em mesmo `-O2` por conta do aumento no tamanho do código. Mas, se você incluir a dica `inline`, ele o fará confiando de que você tem um bom motivo para querer o inline.

Mas se os custos forem enormes (exemplo, fazer inline de uma função de 1000 linhas dentro de uma que tem menos de 10), o compilador muito provavelmente recusará, mesmo com a dica. Você pode ainda assim forçar usando o seguinte:

```
int cubo(int n) __attribute__((always_inline)); // Isso é específico do GCC. Não funcionará
                                                // em qualquer outro compilador.

inline int cubo(int n) {
    return n*n*n;
}
```

Me voltando agora para a sua questão específica. O inline tem dois lados bons e um lado ruim. A primeira é remover a necessidade de uma chamada de função. Pode parecer pouco, mas organizar os argumentos e fazer o salto para uma região de código possivelmente distante custá alguns ciclos. A segunda é que isso permite mais otimizações no código resultante, como reduzir `3*3*3` para `27` e poupar mais. A desvantagem é o aumento de código. Se uma função de 5 linhas for otimizada em 10 lugares, são 50 linhas a mais de código. E isso pode fazer com que uma função ou o corpo de um loop não caiba no cache de código do processador, e forçar ele a ter que ler memória no meio de uma execução crítica.

De forma simples: Use o `inline` em qualquer função definida em um cabeçalho. Use o `inline` em qualquer função que seja muito pequena e trivial. Não use o `inline` em qualquer outro lugar a não ser que saiba o que está fazendo e tenha certeza de que será uma melhora de performance (fazendo benchmarks).

Answer (score 4):

Compilando com o `g++ 4.8.1`, com a opcao `-O2`, ambos os trechos acima tem exatamente o mesmo codigo assembly (com excessao dos nomes dos labels). Logo, nao existe diferenca e nao ha consumo desnecessario de recursos (pelo menos nesse cenario).

Answer (score 0):

Quando você utiliza o inline, o compilador opta por copiar o corpo da função e substituir na chamada em vez de utilizar a função em si.

Como o @Lucas Virgili comentou, ao utilizar a opção -02 você induz o compilador a maximizar a performance do programa, portanto os códigos resultam no mesmo programa.

No caso de uma função para retornar o cubo de um número, uma outra opção que você tem é usar o #define.