# Qual é a finalidade do uso de funções inline na linguagem C?

Tags: c, funções, desempenho, otimização

Gostaria de saber qual é finalidade de funções **inline** na linguagem *C*? Existe alguma diferença de performance ou outras características que devem ser levadas em consideração em comparação com funções **comuns**?

Exemplo de uma função **inline**:

```
inline void funcao_inline_mensagem()
{
    printf("\nStack OverFlow\nFunção inline.\n\n");
}
```

Exemplo de uma função **comum**:

```
void funcao_comun_mensagem()
{
    printf("\nStack OverFlow\nFunção comum.\n\n");
}
```

*Implementação completa dos dois exemplos para ser reproduzido*:

```
#include <stdio.h>

inline void funcao_inline_mensagem()
{
    printf("\nStack OverFlow\nFunção inline.\n\n");
}

void funcao_comun_mensagem()
{
    printf("\nStack OverFlow\nFunção comum.\n\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    funcao_comun_mensagem();

    funcao_inline_mensagem();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Funções inline em iteração](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27085/3635)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento vou analisar, se for duplicata eu do um voto aqui

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Qualquer compilador decente em C hoje tenta forçar que as funções sejam *inline* sempre que compense fazer isto, independente do que o código determinada. Claro que é possível controlar isto via *switch* de compilação.

A otimização de *inline* coloca o corpo da função no local da sua chamada evitando ter que preparar o ambiente para a nova função - normalmente salvar registradores e cópia de argumentos - e restauração na sua finalização (prólogo e epílogo de função). Isto torna o código mais rápido em determinadas circunstâncias. Nem sempre a otimização consegue reduzir tanto o código, especialmente pode ser difícil evitar cópias de dados.

Só compensa fazer em funções relativamente pequenas e que vão executar muito rapidamente. Estas funções podem ter boa parte do tempo de execução formalizando a função e não processando o que se deseja. Funções com várias instruções e principalmente com laço não costuma compensar.

O compilador costuma ser muito esperto quanto a isto, é raro o programador saber quando fazer *inline* melhor que o compilador sabe.

Há casos que esta otimização habilita outras possíveis otimizações, assim como outras otimização torna o código apto para *inline*.

Se o programador forçar onde não deve, não só pode perder performance, principalmente por encher o cache mais facilmente, como também pode ter alguns problemas nem sempre fáceis de perceber.

Se o programador souber medir (perfilar) a aplicação e determinar que realmente haverá ganho onde o compilador não consegue perceber, afinal isto não é tarefa fácil, então pode ser interessante forçar manualmente.

Em algum momento foi incluído na sintaxe possível para determinar se o código deve fazer, mas os compiladores não costumam se importar muito com isto, alguns ignoram completamente e decidem por conta próprio, outros dão um peso maior quando a sintaxe é usada, mas não garante nada. Claro que um compilador pode fazer o que o programador pediu. Alguns tem até uma outra sintaxe e/ou *switch* que forçam o uso desta otimização.

No seu exemplo provavelmente otimizaria assim:

```
int main(void) {
    printf("\nStack OverFlow\nFunção inline.\n\n");
    printf("\nStack OverFlow\nFunção comum.\n\n");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/hBraPK). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/tlhpbrnr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/InlineExample.c).

No passado o pessoal usava macros para fazer isto. Hoje é completamente desnecessário em compiladores modernos. É bem mais fácil cometer erros com macros. Mas é possível cometê-los também quando tentar forçar o *inline*. Em C ainda há a cultura de uso de macros. Em C++, não.

O `inline` junto com `static` ou `extern` pode ser mais útil e dar uma instrução relevante para o compilador.

- [Documentação do GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html).
- [Documentação do Visual C](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/inline-functions-cpp?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=vs-2019).
- [Documentação geral](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/inline).
- [Artigo na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function) mostrando possíveis problemas.

Comment: Interessante notar que alguns compiladores  fornecem um parâmetro para avisar quando um inline foi ignorado (-Winline no GCC).

Comment: Provavelmente, o compilador tambem troca, na optimizacao, o `printf("...\n")` por `puts("...")`.