# Erro ao usar métodos inline em classes C++: undefined reference to

Tags: c++

Estou optimizando parte de meu código onde alguns métodos que são chamados em loop com muita frequência os estou passando para `inline`, mas ao fazer isso estou recebendo as seguintes mensagens de erro:

E estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

```
In file included from CycloTracker.hpp:15:0,
                 from CycloTracker.cpp:3:
ObjectTracker.hpp:45:14: warning: inline function ‘void ObjectTracker::PrintLeftPartial(cv::Mat&)’ used but never defined
  inline void PrintLeftPartial(cv::Mat &frame);
              ^
ObjectTracker.hpp:46:14: warning: inline function ‘void ObjectTracker::PrintRightPartial(cv::Mat&)’ used but never defined
  inline void PrintRightPartial(cv::Mat &frame);
              ^
ObjectTracker.hpp:43:14: warning: inline function ‘void ObjectTracker::PrintLeftPartial(cv::Mat&, cv::Point)’ used but never defined
  inline void PrintLeftPartial(cv::Mat &frame, cv::Point pt);
              ^
ObjectTracker.hpp:44:14: warning: inline function ‘void ObjectTracker::PrintRightPartial(cv::Mat&, cv::Point)’ used but never defined
  inline void PrintRightPartial(cv::Mat &frame, cv::Point pt);
              ^
....
CycloTracker.o: In function `CycloTracker::processFrames()':
/home/fa/Workspace/contadordeciclistas/CycloTracker.cpp:64: undefined reference to `ObjectTracker::PrintLeftPartial(cv::Mat&)'
/home/fa/Workspace/contadordeciclistas/CycloTracker.cpp:65: undefined reference to `ObjectTracker::PrintRightPartial(cv::Mat&)'
/home/fa/Workspace/contadordeciclistas/CycloTracker.cpp:104: undefined reference to `ObjectTracker::PrintLeftPartial(cv::Mat&, cv::Point_<int>)'
/home/fa/Workspace/contadordeciclistas/CycloTracker.cpp:105: undefined reference to `ObjectTracker::PrintRightPartial(cv::Mat&, cv::Point_<int>)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:56: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Já compilei todos os arquivos pensando que poderia ser sujeira no código, já compilado, mas não resolve.

Como devo proceder para usar métodos `inline`em classes?

Segue abaixo os códigos que foram transformados em inline:

```
inline void ObjectTracker::PrintRightPartial(cv::Mat &frame, cv::Point pt) {
    char id[10];
    sprintf(id, ">%02d", object_counter->GetLTRPoints());
    cv::putText(frame, std::string(id), pt, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3,
            cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0), 5, CV_AA);
    cv::putText(frame, std::string(id), pt, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3,
            cv::Scalar(0, 255, 255), 3, CV_AA);
}

inline void ObjectTracker::PrintLeftPartial(cv::Mat &frame, cv::Point pt) {
    char id[10];
    sprintf(id, "<%02d", object_counter->GetRTLPoints());
    cv::putText(frame, std::string(id), pt, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3,
            cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0), 5, CV_AA);
    cv::putText(frame, std::string(id), pt, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3,
            cv::Scalar(0, 255, 255), 3, CV_AA);
}

inline void ObjectTracker::PrintLeftPartial(cv::Mat &frame) {
    PrintLeftPartial(frame, config->GetCounterPos(0));
}

inline void ObjectTracker::PrintRightPartial(cv::Mat &frame) {
    PrintRightPartial(frame, config->GetCounterPos(1));
}
```

Chamadas dos métodos acima:

```
...

ObjectTracker ot(config, 30, 50, config->getInterestArea());

...

do {

        *cap >> frame;      // captura um novo frame e processa imediatamente
        full = frame.clone();
...
        ot.PrintLeftPartial(full);
        ot.PrintRightPartial(full);
...
    } while (char(key) != char(27));
```

Então tentei muar o código como sugerido aqui: [Funções inline em iteração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27085/fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-inline-em-itera%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

Mas não deu certo gerando os seguintes erros:

```
In file included from CycloTracker.hpp:15:0,
                 from CycloTracker.cpp:3:
ObjectTracker.hpp:46:8: warning: always_inline function might not be inlinable [-Wattributes]
   void PrintRightPartial(cv::Mat &frame)__attribute__((always_inline));
        ^
ObjectTracker.hpp:45:8: warning: always_inline function might not be inlinable [-Wattributes]
   void PrintLeftPartial(cv::Mat &frame)__attribute__((always_inline));
        ^
ObjectTracker.hpp: In member function ‘void CycloTracker::processFrames()’:
ObjectTracker.hpp:45:8: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘void ObjectTracker::PrintLeftPartial(cv::Mat&)’: function body not available
CycloTracker.cpp:64:28: error: called from here
   ot.PrintLeftPartial(full);
                            ^
In file included from CycloTracker.hpp:15:0,
                 from CycloTracker.cpp:3:
ObjectTracker.hpp:46:8: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘void ObjectTracker::PrintRightPartial(cv::Mat&)’: function body not available
   void PrintRightPartial(cv::Mat &frame)__attribute__((always_inline));
        ^
CycloTracker.cpp:65:29: error: called from here
   ot.PrintRightPartial(full);
                             ^
Makefile:65: recipe for target 'CycloTracker.o' failed
make: *** [CycloTracker.o] Error 1
```

O código ficou da seguinte forma no que mudei:

```
 void PrintLeftPartial(cv::Mat &frame, cv::Point pt)__attribute__((always_inline));
 void PrintRightPartial(cv::Mat &frame, cv::Point pt)__attribute__((always_inline));
 void PrintLeftPartial(cv::Mat &frame)__attribute__((always_inline));
 void PrintRightPartial(cv::Mat &frame)__attribute__((always_inline));
```

Comment: A que ficheiro pertence o excerto de código que postou? Mostre o código relativo a esses métodos tanto no ficheiro header como no source.

Comment: Olá @aslg este código será opensource, porém sou vou liberá-lo publicamente quando estiver tudo acertado, se for o caso me mande seu e-mail que lhe dou acesso ao repositório no GitBucket. Estou fazendo isso para que todo o código fique bem estruturado antes de liberar e evitar muitas atualizações desnecessárias publicamente.

Comment: A questão não é ser open source, eu só queria confirmar que a definição dos métodos era feita no .cpp e a declaração no .h. O que no caso de funções inline não é correto. Mas o André já respondeu.

Answer (score 2):

As funções declaradas com `inline` precisam estar **definidas** (isto é, devem possuir um corpo) na mesma *translation unit* em que são usadas. Uma *translation unit* é um arquivo fonte (`.cpp`) e todos os *headers* (`.hpp`) que ele inclui.

Na prática, quando se declara uma função *inline* em um *header*, a implementação dela deve estar junto. Pode ser tanto junto com a declaração ou mais abaixo.

Isto vale para funções livres ou funções que são membros de classes (métodos).

**Exemplo:**

```
inline void function1();  // declarada aqui, definida abaixo
inline void function2() {  // declarada e definida aqui
    // ...
}

class A {
public:
    inline void method1();  // declarado aqui, definido abaixo
    inline void method2() {  // declarado e definido aqui
        // ...
    }
};

void function1() {
    // ...
}

void A::method1() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Obrigado André, eu não sou muito adepto de colocar a implementação dos códigos junto a declaração das classes e suas assinaturas, ainda mais no arquivo header. Como posso então solucionar situações como esta onde preciso que o algoritmo seja optimizado evitando ao máximo ouso do stack? eu tenho tentado reduzir o máximo o número de parâmetros nas funções parametrizando a criação das classes e criando funções de set/get para atualizar tais parâmetros só quando realmente necessário.

Comment: @Delfino, colocar implementação em headers tem suas desvantagens mesmo, mas se quiser evitar que seja feita uma chamada de função, o compilador precisa enxergar a implementação quando estiver compilando a chamada. Note que inline não necessariamente reduz o tamanho, reduz o uso do stack ou deixa o programa mais rápido. Antes de fazer micro-otimizações como essas, sugiro analisar o desempenho do programa para verificar onde realmente estão os gargalos, pois pode ser que esteja só piorando.